# I'm selecting object incorrectly using jquery

Tags: javascript, adobe-edge

**Javascript**

---

```
var rewardObj = myComp.getStage().createChildSymbol("reward", "Stage");
    $(rewardObj).css
    ({
        left:500,  //originSize[2].left,
        top:500  //originSize[2].top
    });
```

`$(rewardObj).css` does nothing and `rewardObj.css` throws error.

How would I select this object that I just made and move it over. I've used offset successfully in the past to move objects but this one won't budge. I'm thinking that I am selecting it wrong.

Comment: I am not an Adobe-edge person, but shouldn't it be... `$(rewardObj.element).css`

Comment: I'm not an edge person either. Your answer was correct, put it as an answer and I will mark it correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use the exposed element and not the object

```
$(rewardObj.element).css()
```